# RefreshAheadCache not calling @cacheable annotated methods

Tags: java, spring, ehcache

I am trying to implement RefreshAheadCache with @cacheable annotation but to use it i have to define a CacheLoader which will used to refresh cache. The implementation of CacheLoader is making lots of duplication in code.Can it be avoided by using the methods already annotated by @cacheable?

Answer (score 0):

In my case i work with micro-services and i need some sync request to be cached and updated all the time, I've used **asynchronous messages** in order to update cache with @CachePut.
U can also use **scheduled task** with **@CachePut method** to refresh the cached data.